# Typescript - Preserve concrete object shape

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is it possible in TypeScript for a function to accept any generic **object**, but preserve the **concrete object shape** in the type information?

I'm trying to create an interface like this:

```
interface Object {
    state(): Object
}

Object.prototype.state = function () { ... }
```

in a way that the output of `state()` preserves the concrete object shape in the type information. But if I use the code above and do:

```
let obj = {somekey: 1}.state()
```

`obj` wil have a type of `Object`, instead of `{somekey: number}`.

---

This can easily be done with Arrays, because they are generalised on their members. Doing:

```
interface Array<T> {
    state(): Array<T>
}

Array.prototype.state = function () { ... }

let arr = [1].state()
```

will preserve `arr`'s type as `number[]`.

---

**How can I do the same with Objects, please?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a `this` parameter?

```
interface Object {
    state<T>(this: T): T
}

Object.prototype.state = function () { return this }

let obj = { somekey: 1 }.state()
//  ^? { somekey: number }
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXz49m)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot do this with `Object.prototype`, but you can surely write a function like this:

```
function identity<T>(input: T): T { return input; }
```

it will preserve all type information it can gain when you call it, for example:

```js
// x has type { somekey: number }
const x = identity({somekey: 1});
```

[Try it in the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFQD4AKGMABxCgC58BKWxAb0QCc0oRWkzKpEAvgG4AUCIgIAzvwAeiALzJ0mGDmJNJcALZoA1mmzVEARgF0hQA)